# write a program that repeatedly prompts a user to supply score(out of 100) java

Tags: java

write a program that repeatedly prompts a user to supply score(out of 100) on a test for 5 students once the program has real all score it should produce a table with the following headings (and automatically fill in the rest of the table) for example

```
                   Student No #              Score(out of 100)
                      1                             55

                      2                             66
```

The program should them calculate the total score

Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test33 {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner (System.in);

        int scores[] = new int [100];
        int counter = 0;
        int sum = 0;    
        int input = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter score out of 100 or negative to break.");
            input = kbReader.nextInt();

            if (input < 0) {
                break;
            } else if (input > 100) {
                System.out.println("Score must be out of 100");
            } else {
                scores[input]++;
                counter++;
                sum += input;
            }
        } while (input > 0);

        System.out.println("Score\t# of occur...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "\t" + scores[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("The mean score is " +(sum/counter));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and try to do the work. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: can you help me now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`scores[input]++;` if you want to assign value to your array `scores[]` you must corrected like i did below.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner kbReader= new Scanner (System.in);
        int scores[] = new int [100];
        int counter = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int input = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter score out of 100 or negative to quit.");
            input=kbReader.nextInt();
             if(input<0) {
                 break;
             }
             else if (input>100) {
                System.out.println("Score must be out of 100");
            } else {
                scores[counter]=input;
                counter++;
                sum+=input;
            }
        } while (input>0);
        if(counter != 0){
            System.out.println("Score\t# of occur...");
            for(int i =0; i<100; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + "\t" + scores[i]);
            };
            System.out.println("The mean score is " +(sum/counter));
        }
    }
```

Comment: why the down vote ?

Comment: I don t know thank you can you see the first thing i wrote i want like this

Comment: accept my answer then and up vote me

Comment: i just edited your program little

Comment: @ElarbiMohamedAymen I didn't downvote, but it might be because one of these two reasons: 1. You answered an "on hold" question or probably: 2. Your answer is code only. So please add at least some comments on what you did change and why.